This page isn’t working right now "MyDomain" redirected you too many times. Try deleting your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
I have application which I have hosted in IIS, I added it in SubDomain(AppCore) with separted ApplicationPool
The Problem is .... It works fine in the server with the domain but outside Gives me
This page isn’t working right now "MyDomain" redirected you too many times.
Try deleting your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
Note that :-

The Project Works With Blazor and Dotnet 8

There are many projects in the same Domain but they work fine (DotnetFramework)

I already installed Hosting Bundle and Dotnet 8 SDKs

There are shared Configuration File with configEncKeyAes

When I inspect it gives me only No content available because this
request was redirected IIS

This is My Cors
app.UseCors(builder =>
{
builder
.AllowAnyOrigin()
.AllowAnyMethod().SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
.AllowAnyHeader();
});
_


I tried Checking Permissions of the folder but another application folder in the same domain with different subdomain works with the same persmissions
Edit
Itried All  Jalpa's advices

try to delete cookie and cache and try again to access the site with no hope

make sure you do not have any url rewrite rule set up in the iis which is causing this redirect But am not experienced so here is my url rewrite


)enable iis failed request tracing to get more detail about the issue and also am not experienced so here is my failed request tracing

-enable application logging and also check that added in my code
like that in Program.cs
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");




You checked all irrelevant items. Go back to a privacy tab of your web browser and use its developer tools to see into the redirection (30x) responses for hints.

I already did that but no thing when I inspect it gives me only
No content available because this request was redirected IIS

1)have you tried using different browser? try to delete cookie and cache and try again to access the site. 2)make sure you do not have any url rewrite rule set up in the iis which is causing this redirect 3)enable iis failed request tracing to get more detail about the issue 4)enable application logging and also check that

I did all your comment Mr Jalpa and added in my question to see it

You will have to edit the question to include screen shots or video clips to support your statement of "I already did that but no thing when I inspect it gives me only No content available because this request was redirected IIS". Keep in mind we won't be able to see your screen over the internet, so we don't know what you might have missed.

you can check the logs which is generated by failed request tracing to get more detail abut the issue and i noticed that your rule has condition which is using {HTTP_HOST and pattern is localhost i would like to suggest you to add your domain name instead there
